# R - Draw text in graph based on axis limits to avoid collision

Tags: r

The `wordcloud` library in R provides a neat way of visualizing a bag of words.  I'm doing latent semantic analysis and want to to visualize spatially organized words.  I've been reworking the `wordcloud` function from the library to plot spatially organized words without collision.

The issue I've run into is the basic premise of the algorithm.  I loop through each word, and measure its size.  Then, using the `overlap` function to check if the word boxes overlap, I slide words along their vectors from the origin until they do not overlap.  Now with a list of boxes, none of which overlap I can draw this plot:
[image: Plot of boxes]

However, when I use the `text` function to write the words, I get collisions in my words:
[image: Plot of words colliding]

How can I force the text to draw within the box it originally measured to fit inside?  I'm pretty sure the problem is related to how `cex` sizes data relative to the number of pixels in the graph and not the limits of the axis but I don't know how to force the text to size based on the axis instead of the pixels.  Alternatively, if there's a way to set the pixels in the graphic and some general rules on how to increase the number of pixels to resize text, I'd be interested to know that too.

Here is the data and code to reproduce:

```
x = c(0.0224632572704955, 0.0789587202250317, 0.0274591067722305, -0.0215217178576816, -0.0463136563269626, 0.0777315272157781, -0.0136566199077556, -0.0822360321803568, 0.01830065120482, 0.0837054635574331, -0.0838847576602805, 0.0581030843550272, -0.0846639528682175, -0.0363582203093014, -0.0835228445897983, -0.0857369307718219, -0.0278922709863537, 0.0849891449442603, 0.0778496060942224, 0.0494913027256782, -0.0861355504659213, 0.0831126881041073, 0.0681440084766314, -0.0650637986694017, -0.0863135597714858, -0.0373928848380089, 0.074049835693315, 0.0398077951711342, 0.0843457836924724, -0.0899133240081401, 0.0871469163578526, -0.0213824408924798, -0.0882376644590973, 0.000804796205293155, 0.0790127624196678, 0.0131045301900216, -0.0097660701059642, 0.060740028037966, -0.0924082870436164, -0.0251299367403581, -0.0926467825295682, -0.0141241186540234, -0.00310159424174361, 0.0787547867577223, -0.0260184580833716, 0.0517140709157018, -0.0491806875142526, -0.00524874012683386, -0.00464000490379075, -0.00420786759489088, 0.00322708905712382, -0.101134456332954, -0.0418549470890533, 0.102100219195374, -0.071862111421196, -0.0434097834006479, 0.0776191187925381, 0.1060046720406, -0.0272119968043285, -0.106816653394793, 0.0287332895600156, -0.0912972395214369, -0.0366978670141858, -0.00838648870281447, 0.115639532976652, 0.0361645175825202, 0.0713906746569677, -0.0431317109494537, -0.028564774163145, -0.00523293700560141, -0.00575635646273777, -0.0331782186958773, 0.124661327465304, 0.0315968070860678, -0.0558444285994164, -0.114728260657278, -0.0217221489719173, 0.136336954261077, -0.137719537096706, 0.0641498138158443, -0.139031136774261, 0.00680615901169146, -0.0379560303006893, 0.0475675308733084, -0.141738379598886, 0.0619691952983009, -0.0324363288760584, 0.0350539739326913, 0.0076137234015135, -0.0739266927217484, 0.0372857817004895, 0.153202967109765, -0.0155256753396782, 0.00857420592583181, -0.177745604714841, 0.0795229711787737, -0.0471817920012264, -0.02409890273062, 0.196853164152666, 0.204447953262544)

y = c(-0.0752776571230846, -0.00672122916072416, 0.0758086939339219, 0.0785861789639402, -0.0677055410096309, 0.0272785745148846, -0.0813248054739799, 0.0078475780115705, 0.0810146964880099, -0.00478084767048896, 0.00565925463584872, -0.0608790343449287, -0.00555148434178386, -0.0766928751630864, 0.0169646486204334, -0.00334540779833788, 0.0816797036428977, 0.0159111526606456, -0.0377749477564506, 0.0713097047786406, 0.0156471598878643, -0.0276247455980099, 0.0553499635679889, -0.0602588336256788, 0.0203869390323236, 0.0810150278030348, -0.0497827486612123, -0.0799237894454277, -0.0302989442794288, -0.00298711542054578, 0.0236117049639803, -0.0877260872513847, -0.0193599518017899, -0.0908245510012227, -0.0458884920692699, 0.0911063173756906, -0.0916168143543014, -0.0695525217155883, 0.00250090928101712, 0.0891631284676921, 0.00538569085280678, 0.0919523561635045, 0.0940243248638534, 0.0524309559381309, -0.0912540520367487, 0.0800810133995442, -0.0840852427280262, -0.0984769093381384, -0.0985077379630162, -0.0987069709043514, -0.0989748998527878, 0.00452437059722756, -0.0930322733809224, 0.00069319951483364, 0.0740813318736554, 0.0948855232245366, 0.070645224239989, -0.0103845525763274, -0.103024065101316, -0.00789743078596155, 0.105453142673941, 0.0652869710460866, -0.10890208867039, -0.114697484904734, 0.00413462223558936, 0.110353491923549, 0.0944715994210254, 0.110990259989688, 0.115707989007745, -0.120175636155138, -0.120501392622881, 0.1163418318335, -0.0134237550525085, 0.122300074894697, -0.114937000286942, 0.0634133444114911, 0.132638479157556, 0.00851766613319355, -0.00269271356832806, 0.12226959905812, -0.00682649454407891, 0.13966123914174, 0.135636860115536, 0.133453551172787, 0.0124344798034275, -0.13074953842002, 0.141239398728931, 0.141869629560279, -0.152407018146679, -0.133604473268183, -0.148181211362048, 0.00171078006359565, 0.15792413596998, -0.177085008252531, 0.00233033011911132, -0.159325513391783, 0.172886877895966, -0.187762962706901, -0.0305548311528385, -0.00860796795425707)

words = c("self", "due", "pretty", "retire", "location.", "free", "oriented", "different", "notice", "excel", "environment", "superior", "cooperate", "stability", "goal", "effective", "value.", "important", "now", "practice", "employer", "last", "top", "strength", "genuine", "significant", "sustainable", "proud", "meet", "decent", "research", "specialty", "grew", "success.", "lead", "provide.", "wage.", "manager.", "knowledge", "nothing", "impact", "salary.", "thing", "type", "progress", "pursue", "show", "play", "result.", "principles", "realize", "limited", "time", "deal", "special", "think", "place", "door", "throughout", "effort.", "want", "treat", "still", "raise", "everyday", "texas", "something", "well", "reputable", "recognizes", "origin", "organic", "day.", "resources", "quit", "supervisor", "result", "customer", "daily", "success", "coworkers.", "without", "task", "solid", "growth.", "succeed", "workforce", "talent", "provide", "see", "tackle", "deliver", "quality", "present.", "decisions.", "really", "program", "year.", "gain", "education")

library(wordcloud)

freq = rep(1,length(x))
max.words = 100
min.freq = 1
scale = c(0.7,.1)
colors='black'

tails <- "g|j|p|q|y"
last <- 1
nc<- length(colors)

dfc <- sqrt(x^2+y^2)

overlap <- function(x1, y1, sw1, sh1) {
  s <- 0
  if (length(boxes) == 0)
    return(FALSE)
  for (i in c(last,1:length(boxes))) {
    bnds <- boxes[[i]]
    x2 <- bnds[1]
    y2 <- bnds[2]
    sw2 <- bnds[3]
    sh2 <- bnds[4]
    if (x1 < x2)
      overlap <- x1 + sw1 > x2-s
    else
      overlap <- x2 + sw2 > x1-s

    if (y1 < y2)
      overlap <- overlap && (y1 + sh1 > y2-s)
    else
      overlap <- overlap && (y2 + sh2 > y1-s)
    if(overlap){
      last <<- i
      return(TRUE)
    }
  }
  FALSE
}

ord <- rank(-dfc, ties.method = "random")
words <- words[ord<=max.words]
freq <- freq[ord<=max.words]
dfc <- dfc[ord<=max.words]
x <- x[ord<=max.words]
y <- y[ord<=max.words]

ord <- order(dfc,decreasing=FALSE)
words <- words[ord]
freq <- freq[ord]
x <- x[ord]
y <- y[ord]
words <- words[freq>=min.freq]
freq <- freq[freq>=min.freq]
x <- x[freq>=min.freq]
y <- y[freq>=min.freq]

rStep <- .05
normedFreq <- freq/max(freq)
size <- (scale[1]-scale[2])*normedFreq + scale[2]
boxes <- list()
xy <- list()

plot.new()
op <- par("mar")
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))

for(i in 1:length(words)){
  x1<-x[i]
  y1<-y[i]
  if(x1==0 & y1==0){
    bigger<-sample(c(1,2),1)
    bSign<-sample(c(-1,1),1)
    ratio<-sample(c(-1,1),1)
  } else {
    coords<-c(x1,y1)
    bigger<-which.max(abs(coords))
    ratio<-coords[-bigger]/coords[bigger]
    bSign<-sign(coords[bigger])
  }
  wid <- strwidth(words[i],cex=size[i])
  ht <- strheight(words[i],cex=size[i])
  #mind your ps and qs
  if(grepl(tails,words[i]))
    ht <- ht + ht*.2
  isOverlaped <- TRUE
  while(isOverlaped){
    print(paste0(words[i],": ",overlap(x1-.5*wid,y1-.5*ht,wid,ht)))
    if(!overlap(x1-.5*wid,y1-.5*ht,wid,ht)){
      #rect(x1-.5*wid,y1-.5*ht,x1+.5*wid,y1+.5*ht)
      boxes[[length(boxes)+1]] <- c(x1-.5*wid,y1-.5*ht,wid,ht)
      xy[[length(xy)+1]] <- c(x1,y1)
      isOverlaped <- FALSE
    }else{
      if(bigger==1){
        x1<-x1+rStep*bSign
        y1<-y1+rStep*ratio
      } else {
        x1<-x1+rStep*ratio
        y1<-y1+rStep*bSign
      }
    }
  }
}

points<-do.call(rbind,boxes)
points<-rbind(cbind(points[,1],points[,1]+points[,3]),cbind(points[,2],points[,2]+points[,4]))
lims<-c(min(points[,1]),max(points[,1]))
lims<-c(-max(abs(lims)),max(abs(lims)))

plot.window(c(min(points[,2])*1.05,max(points[,2])*1.05),c(min(points[,1])*1.05,max(points[,1])*1.05))

for(i in 1:length(words)){
  cc <- colors[sample(1:nc,1)]
  text(xy[[i]][1],xy[[i]][2],words[i],cex=size[i],offset=0,col=cc)
  #rect(boxes[[i]][1],boxes[[i]][2],boxes[[i]][1]+boxes[[i]][3],boxes[[i]][2]+boxes[[i]][4])
}
par(mar=op)
```

Comment: @rawr I've lumped the code together now.  My apologies, I was trying to be very descriptive with the code but ended up leaving key elements out.

Comment: good, that fixed it. are you using the same size device for both plots? if you just use a larger region, the words dont overlap. the boxes look slightly smaller to me, so that is why the words aren't fitting. also, if you call the for loop more than once, the size of the text/boxes shrinks, but you're probably not doing that

Comment: @rawr - both of those graphs are using the same device (in RStudio, the window size wasn't changed).  When I zoom, the problem is alleviated.  When I draw these in a Shiny app, I can make the graphic larger to adjust for this.  But, even then, I could end up where a user makes selections and there are word collisions.  If I could simply draw the words relative the axis instead of then no collisions should occur (a la the `wordcloud` plot from `library(wordcloud)`. I should also mention, `wordcloud` will drop words that don't fit, I'm trying to avoid doing that.

Comment: The boxes definitely look a bit smaller than the words end up being, do the axes limits change? Should you force the axes limits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `strWidth` and `strHeight` functions calculate the width and height based on the current coordinate system.  But when you push the boxes out that changes the set of coordinates, so that when you re-plot the data the heights and widths no longer match the text (the boxes look good because the coordinates scale with the coordinate system).  Think if you moved a single box far away, all the boxes would shrink to match the new coordinate system.

A couple of options:

Start with a plot large enough such that the boxes will not reach the boundaries and change the coordinate system.

Figure out how much the overall range increased and shrink the text an appropriate amount using the `cex` argument.

recomputed the size of the box with the new coordinate system on each iteration so the boxes match the actual size of the text.

Comment: I am now starting with a `plot.window(c(-1,1),(-1,1))`, drawing all the words with a `cex=1` and then checking the boxes to see if they exceed the limits.  If they do, I'm shrinking `cex` by a factor, checking again, etc... until I have a size which draws all the words.  Then I draw the words.

Is this in line with your suggestion?  Or were you thinking slightly differently?

Comment: @Mark, that is along the lines of what I was thinking, and if it works then go for it.